# PHP: remove string character found in another string

Tags: php, string

I am trying to compare two strings and remove any characters that appear in second string.
For example:

```
$stringA="abcdefg" ;
$stringB="ayfcghifh" ;
```

I want $`stringB` to be `"yhih"`. Are there any ways to do it? 
Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str_replace(str_split($stringA),'',$stringB);
```

Answer (score 3):

echo ereg_replace("[" . $stringA . "]", "", $stringB);

would be a convenient way to do so.

---

Or using preg_replace()

```
$stringB = preg_replace('/[' . preg_quote($stringA, '/') . ']/', '', $stringB);
```

As an added benefit, you can have case-insensitivity with the /i modifier and Unicode support with /u.

Comment: Good idea but bad execution, you should use preg_replace() instead, as ereg has been deprecated in 5.3. I'll append it to your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: I would highly suggest against ereg_replace. It is depreciated in PHP 5.3. That and for something this simple, str_replace will do just fine, no need for a regular expression.

Comment: I would definitely recommend that approach over `str_replace()` as it is more flexible and its performance is in the same order of magnitude.

Comment: Oops, preg_replace is the better choice, of course. The str_replace() approach seems wiser anyway, since you don't have to worry about escaped characters either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple needles in `str_replace()` to remove each character from `$stringA`. Assuming we're talking about single-byte encoding, you can use `str_split()` to separate each character, which gives you:

```
$stringB = str_replace(str_split($stringA, 1), '', $stringB)
```